# Permanently save intent from other activity (with two values) to listview

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I'm trying to save two values from an activity (where the user can put in two different values, one String value and one integer value) in the listview from another activity. In the first activity, it shows a list with a course and the amount of points for that course in one listview, like this:

Course: English 
Points: 4

Now, the problem is, everytime I want to put in another value using the add_course_actitivty, it overwrites the previous value. I've looked at different solutions, like with sharedpreferences ([Add items to listview from other activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072055/add-items-to-listview-from-other-activity)), but this uses only one value and if I try to work with sharedpreferences, it overwrites the other value in the sharedpreferences, but I want users to add multiple courses and corresponding points. Also on restart, it deletes the values in the listview (I read to prevent this you need to store it in sharedpreferences, but this doesn't work the way I need it to be)

KeuzeActivity.class (shows the listview):

```
public class KeuzeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FloatingActionButton fab_add;
    private String student_naam;
    private ListView keuze_list;
    boolean wantDelete;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private String vak;
    private int ec;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_keuze);

        // setting title
        student_naam = getIntent().getStringExtra("student");
        setTitle("Keuzevakken en projecten van " + student_naam);


        //initialzing elements
        fab_add = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab_add);
        keuze_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.keuze_list);

        //initializing list
        final ArrayList<Course> courseItems = new ArrayList<Course>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Course>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, courseItems);
        keuze_list.setAdapter(adapter);


        // checks if intent has required values, put it in listview
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("vak") && getIntent().hasExtra("ec")) {
            vak = getIntent().getStringExtra("vak");
            ec = getIntent().getIntExtra("ec", ec);
            courseItems.add(new Course(vak, ec));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        // make fab go to other activity
        fab_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(KeuzeActivity.this, add_course_activity.class));
            }
        });


        // long press deletes item
        keuze_list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                showDeleteDialog();
                if (wantDelete) {
                    courseItems.remove(position);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
                return true;

            }
        });

    }



    private void showDeleteDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder infobuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        infobuilder.setCancelable(false);
        infobuilder.setTitle("Vak/project verwijderen");
        infobuilder.setMessage("Weet je zeker dat je het vak of project wilt verwijderen?");
        final TextView text = new TextView(this);
        // action when pressed OK
        infobuilder.setPositiveButton("Ja", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                wantDelete = true;
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        infobuilder.setNegativeButton("Nee", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                wantDelete = false;
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        infobuilder.show();

    }

}
```

add_course_activity.class (let's users input course and points)

```
public class add_course_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText course_edit;
    private EditText ec_edit;
    private Button save_btn;
    private String student_name;
    private int ec;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_course);
        setTitle("Voeg vak of project toe");
        final Context context = getApplicationContext();

        // initializing elements
        course_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_vak);
        ec_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_ec);
        save_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);



        // action on savebutton
        save_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (course_edit.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && ec_edit.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 ) {
                    ec = Integer.parseInt(ec_edit.getText().toString());
                    Intent goBack = new Intent(add_course_activity.this, KeuzeActivity.class);
                    goBack.putExtra("vak", course_edit.getText().toString());
                    goBack.putExtra("ec", ec);
                    goBack.putExtra("student", PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("student_name", student_name));
                    startActivity(goBack);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Voer juiste informatie in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Course.java class (getters and setters + with toString method)

```
public class Course {
    private String vak;
    private int ec;

    public Course(String vak, int ec) {
        this.vak = vak;
        this.ec = ec;
    }

    public String getVak() {
        return vak;
    }

    public void setVak(String vak) {
        this.vak = vak;
    }

    public int getEc() {
        return ec;
    }

    public void setEc(int ec) {
        this.ec = ec;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("Vak: " + vak + "\n" + "Punten: " + ec);
    }
}
```

Note that my code isn't clean or done, but to get further I need to fix this problem.

Comment: Let me understand this, So basically when the user accesses the add course, and adds a course, this adds it to the listView (Without overwriting), but when he closes and opens the application, it is reset to the last course only without the previous ones?

Comment: This is how it works --> the user opens KeuzeActivity, it sees a list with the courses and points --> user wants to add new course, so clicks the fab, the fab opens the add_activity_course --> user can put in course name and points --> on save it shows the course in KeuzeActivity.java --> user closes app, reopens it, everything is gone.

Comment: So you don't have a back button, is that correct?

Comment: Not yet, want to implement that later.

Comment: So you want all courses gone when the user leaves your application and reopen it ?

Comment: No, that's the problem: I want the courses to be saved (with corresponding points). Now, if the user reopens the app (or switches activity), the whole listview content is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several way to do it. As other replies have suggested you can use an SQLLite database and add data to  a course table and retrieve data from it.

If you find Db approach to complicated/heavy

You could also use SharedPreferences what you need to do is figure a way to store a string that represent a list of course. It is not the best way to approach it but it will work.

Lets say you choose to serialize your Course object with  "vac-ec"

Then you just store a serialized list of course. Example "vac1-ec1,vac2-ec2"

When you need to add a course you juste grab the previous string split it to list, append the new course to the list and re-serialize the list to a string to encode it.

Other solution could be to use Realm.

Comment: But how do I add to sharedpreferences without overwriting the values stored in the label? Cause if I'm right, you save a value under a keyname, like "course". If I call the function .getString("course"), it gives a certain value. But when I call the function SharedPreferenceManager.putString("course", coursename) it overwrites the previous value saved in the label.

Comment: The idea is to get the value before you save it. You get the string from shared preferences you add what you need to it and you save it back

Answer (score 0):

You should used SQLiteDatabase and create a table with valid attributes and insert your new values into them

Answer (score 0):

Try by storing the records in SQLite, and get it when you want to show.

By this, You can have a track of all added items. And you can show the items you want.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now things are clearer. As answered by @Dwijraj, when storing what potentially will be a large set of data, for maximum control it is best to use SQLite.
You can read more about the different Saving Data methods here:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

SharedPreferences are best used to store small amounts of information, like storing the settings of an application. [Mute] for example. Or a highscore in case of a game.

A Database is a better option when it comes to storing large pieces of data that you will potentially manipulate.

Your data structure can be something like this, Courses table containing Unique_ID , Course Name, Course Level, Course summary.
A table for English for example which will contain
Exams, Scores, Duration.

There are a lot of things you can do.

Comment: Alright, I will take a look at that. Thanks for the help! I will update this post if I fixed my issue.